# Access 2016 & SQL: Totaling two columns, then subtracting them

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say I have a MoneyIN and a MoneyOUT column. I wish to total these entire columns up so I have a sum of each, then I wish to subtract the total of the MoneyOUT column from the total of the MoneyIN column. I also want to display a DateOF column and possibly a description (I think I can do that by myself).

This would be the original database where I get my information from:

```
 +-------------+------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
    | Location ID | Location Address | Date Of | Money In | Money Out |
    +-------------+------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
    |           1 | blah             | date    |    10.00 |      0.00 |
    |           2 | blah             | date    | 2,027.10 |     27.10 |
    |           2 | blah             | date    |     0.00 |   2000.00 |
    |           1 | blah             | date    |     0.00 |     10.00 |
    |           3 | blah             | date    |  5000.00 |      0.00 |
    +-------------+------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to be able to type in a location ID and then have results show up (in this example I type 2 for the location)

```
+---------+----------+-----------+------+
| Date Of | Money In | Money Out |      |
+---------+----------+-----------+------+
| date    |  2027.10 |     27.10 |      |
| date    |        0 |      2000 |      |
| Total:  |  2027.10 |   2027.10 | 0 |
+---------+----------+-----------+------+
```

I have tried other solutions (One of which was pointed out below), however, they don't show the sum of each entire column, they simply subtract MoneyOUT from MoneyIN for each row. As of now, I am trying to do this in a query, but if there is a better way, please elaborate.
I am extremely new to SQL and Access, so please make the explanation understandable for a beginner like me. Thanks so much!

This is a table referred to below.

```
    +-------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
    | Location ID | Date  | Money IN | Money Out | Total Sum |
    +-------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
    |           1 | date  |      300 |       200 |           |
    |           1 | date  |      300 |       200 |           |
    |           1 | date  |      300 |       200 |           |
    |           1 | total |      900 |       600 |       300 |
    +-------------+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: so do you want to see the 270, 50 and 220? or just 220? or what?  Show sample data and expected results n a grid format.  (mock it up in excel and then use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to convert it to an ascii table and paste that in your question formatted as code.)  a good ascii picture is worth 1000 words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should give you what you want:

```
SELECT DateOf, MoneyIn, MoneyOut, '' AS TotalSum FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT 'Total', SUM(MoneyIn) AS SumIn, SUM(MoneyOut) AS SumOut, 
SUM(MoneyIn - MoneyOut) AS TotalSum FROM YourTable
```

Edit:

You do not need to alter very much to achieve what you want.  In order to get Access to prompt for a parameter when running a query, you give a name for the parameter in square brackets; Access will then pop-up a window prompting the user for this value.  Also this parameter can be used more than once in the query, without Access prompting for it multiple times. So the following should work for you:

```
SELECT DateOf, MoneyIn, MoneyOut, '' AS TotalSum
FROM YourTable
WHERE LocationID=[Location ID]
UNION 
SELECT 'Total', SUM(MoneyIn) AS SumIn, SUM(MoneyOut) AS SumOut, 
SUM(MoneyIn - MoneyOut) AS TotalSum FROM YourTable
WHERE LocationID=[Location ID];
```

However, looking at your table design, I strongly encourage you to change it.  You are including the address on every record.  If you have three locations, but 100 records, then on average you are unnecessarily repeating each address more than 30 times.  The "normal" way to avoid this would be to have a second table, Locations, which would have an ID and an Address field.  You then remove address from YourTable, and in its place create a one-to-many relationship between the ID in Locations and the LocationID in YourTable.

Comment: When I run the code, what I understand is happening is that it is getting all the information from my table, then adding it all up, as desired. However, there is a slight problem in that it can only take one input from each (Money In and Money Out). For example, if I were to have many transactions, how would I alter it to accept many different values from a table? Also, if I would want to limit the results under a certain location (many transactions from many locations), would I use WHERE ((([yourtable].[LocationID])=[Insert LocationID])); ? Thank you for your advice!

Comment: To help you more I would need the table structure, some sample data and given the sample data, what you would like the result to look like. Most things are possible, we just need a hint! If you can supply this, I'll do something in the morning - it's almost 10 pm here 

Comment: I have updated the post above with the table where I get my info from, sample data, and the result. I will look forward to your answer! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: There is still a problem with the code asking for MoneyIn and Money Out and it is only taking 1 value. To elaborate, it prompts MoneyIn (I enter in 300), it prompts Money Out (I enter 200), then prompts LocationID in which case I enter in the correct location and it outputs something like this (I added it to the post, below everything)

Comment: What are your field names? Mine are MoneyIn and MoneyOut?  If your field names are different you will need to replace mine with yours to stop access prompting you for names that don't exist. Note it is not a good idea to use names with spaces otherwise you have to use  square brackets everywhere

Comment: Ah, that was the problem! Thank you so much for all your help and patience!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad you got it sorted. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what you expect without sample data, but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT DateOf, SUM(MoneyIN) - SUM(MoneyOut)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DateOf
```

This will subtract the summed total of `MoneyOut` from `MoneyIn` at each distinct `DateOf`

**Updated Answer**

A `UNION` will let you append a 'Totals' record to the bottom of your result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT CAST(DateOf as varchar(20)) as DateOf, MoneyIn, MoneyOut, '' as NetMoneyIn
      FROM YourTable
      UNION
      SELECT 'Total:', SUM(MoneyIn), SUM(MoneyOut), SUM(MoneyIN) - SUM(MoneyOut)
      FROM YourTable
      ) A
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DateOf <> 'Total:' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, DateOf
```

Some notes.. I used a derived table to ensure that the 'Total' record is last.  Also casted `DateOf` to a string (assuming it is a `date`), otherwise you will have issues writing the string 'Total:' to that column.

Comment: The thing is I don't want it to subtract on each date. I would like the whole column to be totaled. Then I want it subtracted in one query. I added some sample data above as pointed out by xQbert. This is the method I have already tried (I should have specified that). I appreciate your quick feedback!